# asp.net-async pages (comet/reverse ajax/server push)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to develop a comet page using Asp.net. Surfed a lot and found some plugins like Pokein. I feel this [blog](http://www.aaronstannard.com/post/2011/01/06/asynchonrous-controllers-ASPNET-mvc.aspx), to be best suited for my project as it goes in hand with jQuery. But this is in MVC. I wonder if i can do the same with ASP.NET website pages. 
All i need to do is to free up the worker process during the long waiting ajax-call duration. In MVC, async controllers come handy.
 Could someone help me if I can do the same with website pages(say: free up the worker process during the long waiting jquery Ajax call inside the static web method).
 I read about async pages in websites [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx), but this will take a full posback and the page is blocked during the long wait. (basically free up worker process during pre-render and wait for long polling, but the UI still keeps refreshing as the page life cycle is not completed)

Thanks in advance for your advice geeks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Push' style architectures on the web using purely ASP.NET, JavaScript, JQuery, AJAX etc. can be difficult and involved to implement. Normally the route most go is more of a glorified 'pull' model where a timer somewhere client side will check back to the server for the needed data or state required and then preform the necessary action. If you truly want a more of a push architecture with purely web technologies, you will want to look into the long polling 'Comet' architecture. You can read more about it below:

Comet (programming):
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Ideally in the Microsoft world if possible you could jump over to a rich client technology like Silverlight to work with a duplex polling WCF service in which a client subscribed to the server can get updates pushed from the server back to the client. Anytime (as of today)I would need to implement any type of 'push' architecture today I would personally opt for Silverlight as there are numerous examples on how to implement this easily. If you are interested take a look to the (2) links below:

Pushing Data to a Silverlight Client with a WCF Duplex Service:
http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx

How to: Build a Duplex Service for a Silverlight Client:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(VS.95).aspx

Regardless, COMET/Silverlight/Flash, etc. are probably not going to be a widely used option going forward anyways with web sockets in HTML5. But since the spec is not quite ready (see: http://ishtml5readyyet.com/) you might needs to look at using a Silverlight control on your ASP.NET page in the meantime and it will work well.